# How do I configure <path>/.m2/settings*.xml files in Atlassian Bamboo

Tags: maven-3, bamboo

I use Atlassian Bamboo's Maven 3.x task, and have encrypted p/w's in my settings.xml file. In the Maven task, I pass the "-s /path_to/settings.xml" switch to tell Maven where my settings.xml file is. However, this looks for /root/.m2/settings-security.xml file, but I can't write the file in the /root/... path. How do I make my Maven task look for the settings-security.xml file somewhere else?

Or is there a better solution to this than what I'm doing?